# looking for a good Linux program for hindi speech to text

Tags: linux, transcription

I'm looking for a Hindi transcription tool in Linux. It should be able to accept audio files and give textual output. For English, VOSK is pretty good since it recognizes both Indian and US English. Is there anything like that for Hindi?

I was informed about https://kunal-dhawan.weebly.com/asr-system-for-hindi-language-from-scratch.html. But couldn't make out much from it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use the Google API for speech recognition:

- To test it online: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text
- Supported languages: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages (it supports Hindi)

You can [call it via Python](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/ASR_benchmark) or some other language on Linux.

FYI [Is there any decent speech recognition software for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256138/16704)